# Excel VBA Change Color of Series in Pivot Chart

Tags: vba, excel

This is one of those stupid questions that should be really simple, but I can't quite figure out what's wrong, and everything I've found on the Internet hasn't worked.

I just want to recolor the series line in a pivot chart after I change the filters in the pivot table. Here is what I have tried:

```
ThisWorkbook.Charts(ChartName).SeriesCollection(SeriesName) _
Format.Line.ForeColor = RGB(75, 172, 198)
```

That code gives me "subscript out of range" error. I also tried:

```
Sheets(SheetName).ChartObjects(ChartName).Chart.SeriesCollection(SeriesName) _
.Format.Line.ForeColor = RGB(75, 172, 198)
```

as well as

```
 ... .ForeColor.ColorIndex = 3
```

as well as

```
... .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent4
```

But those all give me a "type mismatch" error. Excel's VBA Recorder gives me:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
With Selection.Format.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent4
    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
    .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.400000006
    .Transparency = 0
End With
```

I'm sure I just have some stupid, obvious error somewhere, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to access the color property of a series in a pivot chart. Sometimes it feels like trying to navigate a freakin' labyrinth trying to figure out the cryptic hierarchy of objects that a certain property belongs to in VBA...

Comment: In your first two attempts, what is the value of `ChartName` and `SeriesName`? If either of those refer to a non-existent chart or series name, then the Subscript Out of Range error is expected.  Debug by breaking it down and checking those two arguments.

Comment: Good idea. I just tried to loop through each `Chart`, `Charts`, `ChartObject`, and `ChartObjects` in `ThisWorkbook.Charts` and output the name, and it gave me nothing with any of those objects. But there are for SURE 7 Pivot Charts in my workbook. Does a pivot chart not count as a "chart," and if not, what is it, and how do I access it?

Comment: PivotChart should be an ordinary `ChartObject` that would be iterable through the `Worksheet(_sheetname_).ChartObjects` collection.

Comment: Okay. Yes that does work, and I can access all of the charts that way. But then what is the syntax to access the properties of a specific series in a specific chart?

Comment: Should be `Worksheet(_sheetname_).ChartObjects(_chartname_).Chart.SeriesCollection(_seriesname_)`.

Comment: Right, that's what I'm trying. When I use `... .SeriesCollection(seriesName)` with `seriesName` being a String object, it gives me a "Type Mismatch" error. But when I do `... .SeriesCollection("Series Name")` with the _exact same_ string hard coded in quotes, it works. Thoughts?

Comment: Only thing I can really think of is that it's **not** the exact same string, typo, trailing/leading space or something else in there that you're not seeing.  Does it fail if you use the series index position e.g., `...SeriesCollection(2)`, also?

Comment: Index position works fine. With the string, I am _literally_ doing `Dim seriesName as String`, `seriesName = "Name"`, then `Debug.Print ...SeriesCollection("Name").Name`, works just fine. The very next line is `Debug.Print...SeriesCollection(seriesName).Name`, and I get "Type Mistmatch." Does not make any sense.

Comment: I might have figured it out.

Comment: Did you have a chance to review my answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that you have the makings of a solution with your attempts.  A few things that I found (lots of it in XL Help):

1. Format is a read-only property, which might explain why that wasn't working.
2. Use ChartGroups instead of SeriesCollection
3. From XL Help "There’s no object that represents a single series line; you either have series lines turned on for all points in a chart group or you have them turned off."
4. Instead of declaring the seriescollection, try using Charts(ChartName).ChartGroup(cg)

So, your code might look like:

```
Dim cht as Chart
Dim cg as ChartGroup
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(ChartName)
With cht.ChartGroups(cg)
    .HasSeriesLines = True 'turn on series lines for the chart group
    With .SeriesLines.Border
        .ColorIndex=[pick your color]
    End With
End With
```

Comment: The OP's recorded code shows that he's trying to format the lines connecting points in a line chart series. SeriesLines in your code refers to lines that connect the bars or columns in adjacent categories in a stacked bar or column chart. Not what the OP needed, and from a dataviz point of view, not an effective technique to be using in any case.

Answer (score 0):

What I discover from debugging a simple example is that apparently you cannot assign a `.Name` property to series in a PivotChart.  I would expect this to raise an error, but it does not.  It just passes right over the assignment as if nothing happened.

```
Sub Test()
Dim pivotChart As ChartObject
Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Series
Dim seriesName As String

Set pivotChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
Set cht = pivotChart.Chart
Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

'First look at the name:
Debug.Print srs.Name

'Assign a new name to the string variable
seriesName = "Name"

'Assign the new name from string var to the series
srs.Name = seriesName

'Now review that the name has changed. It hasn't!!
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Name

End Sub
```